# dataframe group by month count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have created a dataframe as below:

```
paystart = datetime.date(2017, 10, 26)
paydate = pd.DataFrame()
paydate['PayDate'] = pd.date_range(paystart, end, freq='14D')
print(paydate.Grouper(freq='M'))
```

I want to count the number instances of date for any month-year combination i.e. Result should look like:

```
 2017-10   1
 2017-11   2
 2017-12   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)  with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html)  or [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`Resampler.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.size.html) output is `DatetimeIndex`:

```
paydate = pd.DataFrame()
paydate['PayDate'] = pd.date_range('2017-10-26', '2017-12-26', freq='14D')
print (paydate)
     PayDate
0 2017-10-26
1 2017-11-09
2 2017-11-23
3 2017-12-07
4 2017-12-21

print(paydate.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='PayDate')).size())
PayDate
2017-10-31    1
2017-11-30    2
2017-12-31    2
Freq: M, dtype: int64

print(paydate.resample('M', on='PayDate').size())
PayDate
2017-10-31    1
2017-11-30    2
2017-12-31    2
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

Or is possible create month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) - output is `PeriodIndex`:

```
print(paydate.groupby(paydate['PayDate'].dt.to_period('m')).size())
PayDate
2017-10    1
2017-11    2
2017-12    2
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```